# Number operator in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, conventions

In quantum mechanics $a^{\dagger}a$ is defined as the number operator, where $[a,a^{\dagger}]=1$. Why cannot we define $aa^{\dagger}$ as number operator instead of the usual definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator $aa^\dagger$ is easily seen to be nothing else than
$$ aa^\dagger = a^\dagger a + 1$$
which is equivalent to $[a,a^\dagger]=1$, a commutator that easily follows from $a\sim (x+ip)/\sqrt{2}$ with some extra coefficients and $[x,p]=i\hbar$, so $aa^\dagger$ is the number operator plus one, i.e. taking values $1,2,3,4,\dots $ instead of $0,1,2,3,\dots$ of $a^\dagger a$. This $a^\dagger a =N+1$ could also be called the "number operator" and written as $N$, except that the convention is one with $N=a^\dagger a$ for the ground state to start at zero.

(The quantum mechanical Hamiltonian is naturally proportional to $(aa^\dagger+a^\dagger a)/2$, the average of the two that has eigenvalues $0.5,1.5,2.5,\dots$, so it basically gives us a compromise in the middle between $a^\dagger a$ and $aa^\dagger$.)